# How do I avoid exceeding the counter limit when using Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm getting the following error from a Pig script:

"Error: Exceeded limits on number of counters - Counters=120 Limit=120"

I have the line "SET pig.disable.counter true;" in my script, which I thought would solve the problem, but it didn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Pig are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pig.disable.counter is supported from Pig 0.9.1

Pig will be ignoring this property in older versions such as 0.8.1

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why this isn't working for me.  Do you happen to know how to avoid this error in Pig 0.8.1?

Comment: I don't think you can. Pig 0.8.1 is an old release, I'd recommend upgrading if possible.